Google Search Console crawled too many fake urls not exisit in website
I'm having a big trouble
Goolge Search Console crawled my website but HTML crawled by Google has too many fake urls not exisit in my website. These urls seem to be appended, illegitimate and fraudulent
This image bellow is HTML google Crawled my website Url, contains too many fake  tag:

This image is my website source:

I'm extremely confused and don't know how to handle it. Please give me advice to handle and prevent it in the future.
Thanks so much for your help!

Unfortunately, it's most likely that your site has been hacked, and the hacker has cloaked the content so it's only seen by Google.
Try viewing the site using Google's user agent, and the content will probably become visible. There is a guide how to do that here.
Third party plug-ins and unpatched sites are usually the cause of this sort of hack.  It's worth googling "plug-in name +exploit" to see if you can find a likely cause.
If you have an old copy of the site, try comparing the files.  Often that can flag-up any backdoors the hacker may have added.
Sorry this won't be what you want to hear - hacks are never fun things to deal with.

many thanks for your suggestion!

Yeah, how helpful! your answer correct 100%
